# Android app to block calls specific numbers for specific times of day

Tags: android

Most of the apps for blocking calls only allow to schedule blocking of all numbers in blacklist.

I am looking for a functionality where you could specify time for answering calls / blocking calls for numbers individually or by groups

E.g. Number A would be allowed to call (will not be blocked) on Mondays from 14.00-16.00
Number B would be blocked for the whole weekends.

If you could add contacts to predefined groups which would share the blocking policy, that would be even better.

If you find it hard to imagine why would anyone need this, then imagine a service number which hundreds of people call to get service, however each customer pays for different quality of service which provides them with different times when they can call.

Price can vary, but I wouldn't expect such an app to cost more than 3-5€ on play store. (though if you find such, but more expensive, please post it anyway)

Comment: Free? If not what budget?

Comment: It is not for me, I will ask, but I presume you ask because you would be willing to develop it, if the price would be reasonable? I think the person would only buy it from store, if it was there already, I don't think he would pay for development. If it would be doing what is requested, I guess the price could be more than for an average app (10€ and more), I would have to ask. But me personally I wouldn't expect an app like this to cost more than 5€ on store

Comment: Sorry I only develop apps that I need for myself (and I make them open source) :-) I asked because good questions must have pricing requirements, see http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: @NicolasRaoul ah, okay :) thanks for the suggestion, I'll edit it

Comment: I need this to block my work messages during the weekend